# Not able to set Record Type on Custom Button

Tags: custom-button, record-type

I have created a custom button that will load a page to create an opportunity in which few fields needs to be prefilled and it should have a specific RecordType. But the issue is all the fields are getting populated but the record is created with the default Record Type and not the RecordType mentioned. This is the code I am using

```
/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=RecordType=0121U000000KDRIQA4,AccountId={!Task.What},Campaign_Member__c={!Task.Campaign_Member__c},CampaignId={!Task.CampaignId__c},ContactId={!Task.Who}
```

I have also tried the below code but nothing seemed to work. It is using the default record type.

```
/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?RecordType=0121U000000KDRIQA4&defaultFieldValues=AccountId={!Task.What},Campaign_Member__c={!Task.Campaign_Member__c},CampaignId={!Task.CampaignId__c},ContactId={!Task.Who}
```

Can anybody please help me on this.

Comment: How did you come up with `/new?RecordType=....` as the format for forcing the record type?

Comment: Can we not update like this? I was using this format to open the page when we click on you and some of the fields will be fetched by default, does recordType data cannot be brought like this?

Comment: Is the recordtype enabled for your profile? If not, it will revert to the default recordtype.

Comment: It was enabled but there was something else restricting it. Also I used Vinay approach as well it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `recordTypeId` is case sensitive and make sure you use 'recordTypeId' to set default record type value.

```
/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?recordTypeId=0121U000000KDRIQA4&defaultFieldValues=AccountId={!Task.What},Campaign_Member__c={!Task.Campaign_Member__c},CampaignId={!Task.CampaignId__c},ContactId={!Task.Who}
```

Comment: Hi @Vinay I tried this but didnt work

Comment: /lightning/o/Opportunity/new?recordTypeId=0121U000000KDRIQA4&defaultFieldValues=AccountId={!Task.What},Campaign_Member__c={!Task.Campaign_Member__c},CampaignId={!Task.CampaignId__c},ContactId={!Task.Who}

Comment: It worked for me and record type is being populated, make sure you have access to record type on opportunity and use correct record id (/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?recordTypeId=0122v000001SmZ2AAK&defaultFieldValues=
Phone__c={!Account.Phone}, field2,field3 etc.,)

Comment: Hey Vinay it worked there was some other logic in the system preventing it but now everything is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Much appreciated